# How move the camera to Annotation?

Tags: ios, swift

Huy Guys, i need you. 
There is a method for the event in swift where I can move the camera ( focus) in the map to move from annotation to annotation?
and if not exists how can i create this?
Scuse me for my bad english!

When i click on button to go to annotation i call this method and it is too fast....how i slow it? i pass the annotation like a parameter....

```
func goToAnnotation(annotation: MKPointAnnotation)
{
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0002, 0.0002)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: annotation.coordinate, span: span)
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`MKMapView` has a method `showAnnotations:animated:`. You can pass this an array of annotations, and the map will zoom and reposition itself to fit in those animations:

```
mapView.showAnnotations(myAnnotationsArray, animated: true)
```

See the full documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/showAnnotations:animated:

Comment: yes did it, but i would to pass from annotation to another perhaps with animation.  How can i do? thanks :)

Comment: You could call this method multiple times with different annotations, and a delay (perhaps wrapping it in dispatch_after to delay it).